# benign warning message in debug when compiling salesforce SDK app view controller stack

Tags: ios, mobile, salesforce, viewcontroller

I get a WARN message in the debug console, please note that the app does not fail, it runs fine however I am curious to know what the WARNing means: "WARN|SFRootViewManager|view controller ((null)) not found in the view controller stack.  No action taken."
Any ideas what this means and what action I should take? I'm only worried (slightly) that this may have an affect later when I add more view controllers to the chain.

Comment: I´m getting this warning too. But i´ve continued with my application, adding more viewcontrollers, and i haven´t had any problems yet. Are you using Salesforce Mobile SDK 2.0 too?

Comment: Yes, I'm using that SDK, I renamed the RootViewColler as far as I remember, do you think that would have something to do with it?

Comment: I'm looking at this in case it has something to do with my app showing a blank white screen in app switcher and momentarily upon returning from background. When the app is backgrounded, I see DEBUG|SFRootViewManager|SFRootViewManager: Presenting view controller (UIViewController). My related question is  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443600/why-does-my-app-appear-as-a-blank-white-screen-in-app-switcher

Comment: I discovered that my issue was due to useSnapshotView in SFAuthenticationManager.h, although the warning in question remains

Comment: It is causing my tablerows to not show.