# Why does my app appear as a blank white screen in App Switcher?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to understand where iOS gets the image from for App Switcher and when. What do I need to change to get control of what appears on App Switcher?

Right now, I can set a breakpoint on the first line of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, my launch screen is visible, but App Switcher shows just a blank white screen with just the green battery rectangle. The App Switcher doesn't seem to pick up any image later in my app either.

I'm doing this in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
```

and later in a called method (after setting up appropriate views) this:

```
MMDrawerController * drawerController = [[MMDrawerController alloc]
                                         initWithCenterViewController:centerView
                                         leftDrawerViewController:leftDrawer];

drawerController.maximumLeftDrawerWidth = LeftDrawerWidth;
drawerController.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureModeTapCenterView;

[imageView addSubview:[self staticToolbar]];
[imageView addSubview:[self dsaToolbar]];

self.window.rootViewController = drawerController;



[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered that my issue was due a feature in the Salesforce SDK I am using. useSnapshotView in SFAuthenticationManager.h can be used to toggle this security option.

Comment: you set the salesforce sdk manager singleton boolean (useSnapshotView) to false in order to remove the white screen. Or you can set snapshotViewCreationHandler to return the view controller you need to show on app switcher.